# How can I find text location with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to find the location of some text on a web page using Selenium.
I can use the isTextPresent function to tell me if the text occurs, but then I want to know where it actually is.

The wider problem is that I want to click on this text.
The problem is that I don't seem to be able to click on this text, which I think is in some control embedded on the page. So, it doesn't seem to be detected as a link or button or option etc. However, I need to click on it to make a selection.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution `xpath=//*[text()='hello']` will click the first clickable element with the text "hello" in the source code. If you want to be more specific, you can add more cases to the xpath like this

```
xpath=//*[@id='exampleId']//*[text()='hello']
```

Now this will click element with text 'hello' that's found after some element with id 'exampleId'.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !
I don't know the answer to how to find the location,
but, the more important bit is to click on that text.

I can just use an XPath locator in the click method, like :-

```
Click(xpath=//*[text()="hello"])
```

This will click on the element that has a text value of "hello".
In my case, this is unique, so that's specific enough.

Comment: _______________ deleted comment and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is great usage and you should answers above. However, I realised, that sometimes Selenium does not allow you to click something, because it thinks the text is hidden by CSS

So far I do not have any workaround for it and instead of clicking a button I am closing completly whole browser window.

But in my case its div hidden by CSS showing actual version number of such application. So I only take a screenshot of it:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File destination = new File("path/to/outputfiles/versionNumber.png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

`${x_axis}=  Get Horizontal Position  xpath=//*[text()="Log files"]
Get Horizontal Position returns the position of 'Log files' wrt the left end(X-axis length).`

the position is an integer value... so can be compared easily as well.