# Selenium Web Page in Text Search

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I make a text call using selenium on a web page?

Should I use searchContext?

I tried using xpath but I get an error.

//***************************
okay all thanks. my code is working :)

```
var link = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*/a[contains(.,'btctrader')]")).Text;
```

Comment: You should post the code you're using. Your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982682/finding-text-on-page-with-selenium-2  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562099/how-can-i-find-text-location-with-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this will check if text exists on the page:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("Text");
```

But this is just one of many ways.  You'd need to be more specific if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: for example. My request text "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570937/selenium-web-page-in-text-search/25572275#25572275"
but i just searching text "stackoverflow.com" and copy all link.